# OSM Map - ways to edit OSM map layers and remove detail in an easy manner similar to mapbox in QGIS?

Tags: openstreetmap

I am using an OSM  map as my base layer, I have been browsing the site to find an answer.
I am exporting specific scales (usually fairly close 1:5000) to the sites. And OSM gives a lot of unnecessary detail at that level.

Is it feasible to "hide" some features of OSM directly within QGIS somehow?

I am attaching an image where you see how that street data becomes awkward noise. Since I will have 5000 of these sites eventually, part of a longer research, I cant do this manually.

I should note I am not a coder/developer. Some answers I saw seem to entail that.

In addition I would also want to edit the symbology for a street, similar to [mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/) whereby you can highlight this as needed i.e. change colour and outlines.

[image]

Comment: Side note to moderator @ PolyGeo – I never noticed my questions are edited by you. I appreciate the effectiveness of clear communication. That said it doesn't hurt to show humanity on these sites either, namely, the appreciation of receiving help from others which for reasons unknown to me you have edited?

Comment: The styles available for geofabrik downloads might be useful: https://github.com/mkoenigb/OSM-Geofabrik_Universal-QML-Style/tree/master

Comment: There is https://github.com/lcoandrade/OSMDownloader plugin, where, after downloading, you can filter out unnecessary features. Or style it.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the answer is this from ahmadhanb.

> "In your case, I would recommend you try using some variant of Vector
> Tile services for the base map.
>
> ESRI OSM vector tile layer. The tile server is here:
> https://basemaps.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/OpenStreetMap_v2/VectorTileServer/tile/z/y/x.pbf

1. Menu Layer > Add Layer
2. Add Vector Tile Layer
3. Check if "service" is selected and click new
4. **Add the link detail as in the screenshot**, it won't work otherwise. So omit the part with tile/z/y/x.pdf. only "https://basemaps.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/OpenStreetMap_v2/VectorTileServer"
5. Click add
6. Voila, you are ready to go
7. In my case I am unchecking almost all labels

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I still need to figure out some things here for my map, but this seems to be a start.